# Designing the UI using Angular2

Tags: rest, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, ngfor

I am looking to build hierarchy structure of an organization in my web-app front-end. We are currently using Angular2.

[image: Details]

This is how it looks like in summarized view:

[image: Details 2]

How it can be done?

Right now I am doing in the following pattern.
1. Load parent group (ABC Company)
2. When someone clicks on it, child organizations should be loaded in the above fashion.

I am trying to store the data in an array & when someone clicks back button in the browser the parent group is getting appended in front of the child group.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Seems like a pretty normal setup... could just have a repeater setup against a custom directive which displays the company's details in the expanded view when active.

```
<div *ngFor="let company of companies" (click)="company.isActive = !company.isActive">
    <my-company-details *ngIf="company.isActive" companyData=company>
</div>
```

Comment: First time when the page loads, I load ABC company and when clicked on the ABC company I get the child group, which is PAN India. I have the same workflow for rest of the groups. When some one clicks on back button, a new api call happens in which I get the parent group. That parent group gets appended infront of the child group. How can I avoid such workflow?Currently, I'm using arrays to store group data that i receive from the server. I thought of sorting the groups inside the array by group ids. But I am getting string value(like : "e8t4hsi8097") in group_id field.